# Optimizations for Raycasting

Tags: graphics, 3d, raycasting

I've been wanting to build a 3D engine starting from scratch as a coding challenge with the end objective of implementing it on a fantasy console.
The best (i.e. most simple?) way I found was raytracing/raycasting. I haven't found much by looking online for raycasting algorithms, only finding point-in-polygon problems (which only tell me whether a ray intersects a polygon or not, not quite my interest since I wouldn't have info about the first intersection nor I'd have the intersection points).

The only solution I could think of is brute forcing the ray by moving it at small intervals and every time check whether that point is occupied by something or not (which would require having filled shapes and wouldn't let me have 2D shapes since they would never be rendered, although none of those is a problem). Still, it looks way too complex performance-wisely.

As far as I know, most of those problems are solved using linear algebra, but I'm not quite as competent as to build up a solution on my own. Does this problem have a practical solution?

EDIT: I just found an algebric solution in 2D which could maybe be expanded in 3D. The idea is:

- For each edge, check whether one of the two vertices are in the field of view (i.e. if O is the origin of every ray and P is the vertex, you have to check first that the point is inside the far point of sight, and then whether the angle with the forward vector is less than the angle of vision). If at least one of the two vertices is inside the field of view, add them to an array E.

  - If we have an array R of rays to shoot and an array of arrays I of info about hit points, we can loop for each ray in R and for each edge in E and then store f(ray, edge) in I, where f is a function that gives us info on whether the ray and the edge collided and where they did.
  - f uses basic linear algebra: both the ray and the edge are, for all purposes, two segments. Two segments are just parts of two lines. Let's say that if the edge has vertices A and B (AB is the vector that goes from A to B) and if the far point is called P (OP is the vector that goes from O to P). We can create two lines, r and s, defined by A + ηAB and O + λOP. After we do a check to see whether r and s are parallel (check if the absolute value of the dot product of AB and OP is equal to the norm of AB times the norm of OP), it's trivial to get the values for η and λ.
  - Now, if η < 0 OR η > 1 we have that the two segments are not colliding.
  - After we've done this for every ray and every edge, we compare every element in each array i in I to see which one had the lowest λ. The lowest λ carries the first collision and hence the data to show on screen.

Everything here is linear algebra, though I fear that it might still be computationally heavy, since there's a lot going on, and it's still only 2D.

Comment: You might want to look at spatial data structures used in ray-tracing, such as BSP and k-D trees.

Comment: What is your geometric model ? Are you asking for a ray/polygon intersection algorithm in 3D ?

Comment: If you plan to use ray casting rather than ray tracing (no secondary rays), it is much more efficient to project and scan-convert the polygons.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I will look into them. Any pointers to specific sources?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Rereading the question now, it seems a bit messy, but, yeah, I wanted to build a 3D rendering engine for a fantasy console. Since I'll build the engine myself, I think I will use a trig-based meshing system (since I will only be dealing with simple geometric shapes, no complex meshing whatsoever), but if I am open to better options.

Also, I happened to understand that ray casting and ray tracing are synonymous, isn't that the case?

Comment: @Leodip: no, read my comment.